# Dijkstra in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I am writing the solution of Dijkstra's algorithm in JS. This is what has happened so far. I need to make it so that the choice of nodes is by recursion. Tell me how to do this better.

```
const size = 6;
сonst maxInt = 999999;
const graph = [
  [null, maxInt, 50, 20, maxInt, 30],
  [null, maxInt, maxInt, maxInt, 10, maxInt],
  [null, maxInt, 20, maxInt, 40, maxInt],
  [null, maxInt, maxInt, maxInt, maxInt, maxInt],
  [null, maxInt, 20, maxInt, 25, maxInt]
];

const nodeParams = (distance, path, visited) => {
  this.dist = distance;
  this.path = path;
  this.visited = visited;
};

let node = [];

for(let i = 1;i < size;i++) {
  node[i] = [];
  for(let j = 1;j < size;j++) {
    node[i][j] = nodeParams(maxInt, 0, false);
  }
};

const dijkstra = () => {
  for(let source = 1; source < size; source++) { 
    node[source][source].dist = 0;
    let minNode, nextNode;
    for(let i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) {
      minNode = i === 1 ? source : nextNode;
      node[source][minNode].visited = true;
      nextNode = null;
      for(let w = 1; w < size; w++) {
        if (!node[source][w].visited) {
          if (node[source][minNode].dist + graph[minNode][w] < node[source][w].dist) {
            node[source][w].dist = node[source][minNode].dist + graph[minNode][w];
            node[source][w].path = minNode;
          }
          if(nextNode === null) {
            nextNode = w;
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

dijkstra ();

let shortestPathString = '';

const getEachPathNode = (source, destination) => {
  if(destination != source && destination > 0) {
    getEachPathNode(source, array[source][destination].path);
    shortestPathString += ' ' + array[source][destination].path;
  }
}

const getShortestPath = (source, destination) => {
  shortestPathString = 'Самый короткий путь от ' + source + ' до ' + destination + ': ';
  if (array[source][destination].dist == maxInt) {
    shortestPathString += 'не связаны';
  } else {
    getEachPathNode(source, destination);
    shortestPathString += ' ' + destination;
  }

  shortestPathString += '.  Расстояние: ' + array[source][destination].dist;
  console.log(shortestPathString);
}

for(let i = 1; i < size; i++) {
  for(let j = 1; j < size; j++) {
    getShortestPath(i, j);
  }
}
```

If there are any comments on the code, I'll be very glad to hear them too. This code does not go into any project, I just just study programming and try to set myself tasks and solve them.

Comment: Something is wrong with this code. Are you sure it's working? The function `nodeParams` modifies `this` which is actually `window` here, and then returns `undefined`. You use the return value to create a matrix `node`, which means you're creating a bunch of `undefined`s in the matrix.